# Literal translation of Aṣṭasāhasrikā Prajñāpāramitā Sūtra

Tags: sutras, translation

What is the literal meaning of Aṣṭasāhasrikā Prajñāpāramitā Sūtra. Everywhere I read it says "The Perfection of Wisdom in 8000 Lines", but that is not a *literal* translation as far as I can tell. What is the literal translation or etymology?

For example, [Sutra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sutra) means "thread", but that is no where in that perfection of wisdom phrase. I read elsewhere, too, that:

> The word Prajñāpāramitā combines the Sanskrit words prajñā "wisdom" with pāramitā "perfection".

So we have the "wisdom perfecting thread" sort of thing. But what is the other word?

Comment: 8000 is the literal translation -- not knowing that sutra though, I don't know whether it's intended literally or metaphorically, perhaps for example as a metaphor for "many", "long", "detailed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Aṣṭasāhasrikā* translates to "eight thousand":

- *aṣṭá* -- eight
- *sahasra* -- thousand

[Sanskrit Numbers](http://veda.wikidot.com/sanskrit-numbers/comments/show)

Answer (score 1):

Aṣṭasāhasrikā: asta (8) sahasara (1000)
Prajñāpāramitā: prajna(wisdom) paramita(perfection)
Sutra: thread/verse

PDF: [THE PERFECTION OF WISDOM IN EIGHT THOUSAND LINES & ITS
VERSE SUMMARY](https://huntingtonarchive.org/resources/downloads/sutras/02Prajnaparamita/Astasahasrika.pdf)
- The Huntington Archive